# Modify abstract appearance

Tags: formatting, koma-script, abstract

there's two tweaks I don't know how to perform:
1. I'd like to remove the small indentation at the beginning of each paragraph.
2. Increase the paragraph break separation.

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half,numbers=noendperiod,abstract=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{nature}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
            headsep=10mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{paralist}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.} 
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont\large}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\ihead{}\ohead{}\chead{\headmark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\markboth{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2014}
{Title \textbullet{} SS 2014} 

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{\textsc{Name Surname}\\[2ex]
\normalsize University Name \\ 
\normalsize \href{mailto:name@domain.com}{name@domain.com}}
\date{}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{12mm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\unskip\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel sem enim. Morbi venenatis nisl vitae elit porttitor maximus. Nullam bibendum nunc iaculis, venenatis nibh eu, gravida urna. Sed semper laoreet ex et finibus. Morbi pharetra massa sit amet bibendum volutpat. Etiam faucibus erat diam, in pharetra urna faucibus sed. Donec aliquet est et eros laoreet iaculis. Donec faucibus enim a augue pretium auctor. 

Cras cursus, leo eu convallis venenatis, urna turpis vulputate velit, et cursus neque lacus a odio. In finibus arcu sit amet odio convallis iaculis. Duis cursus eu tellus et molestie. Donec posuere eu sapien at lacinia. Maecenas in nisl mattis, efficitur mauris in, ullamcorper erat. Suspendisse vel nibh efficitur, posuere dui a, euismod lacus. 

Quisque erat nisi, euismod id nulla et, tincidunt venenatis leo. Aenean in tincidunt magna. Proin elementum ornare viverra. Sed mattis ullamcorper fermentum. Integer pulvinar arcu quis egestas hendrerit. Curabitur ac mauris turpis. Nam aliquam scelerisque volutpat. Pellentesque varius gravida lacus vitae iaculis. 
\end{abstract}

\vspace{5mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should set the headsepline globally, as it sets option `headinclude=true` which is passed to typearea. Or do `recalctypearea` after setting the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be patching the orignial
abstract environment to use `quote` instead of `quotation`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half,numbers=noendperiod,abstract=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\quotation}{\quote}{}{}


\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{killthepixelnow}
\date{}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext\par
    \blindtext\par
    \blindtext\par
\end{abstract}

\vspace{5mm}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using a KOMA class, with the `parskip=half` option, the proper way is to use something like

```
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
```

for the abstract (use `full`, or any of the other available options instead of `half`, according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half,numbers=noendperiod,abstract=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
            headsep=10mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont\large}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{\textsc{Name Surname}\\[2ex]
\normalsize University Name \\ 
\normalsize \href{mailto:name@domain.com}{name@domain.com}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel sem enim. Morbi venenatis nisl vitae elit porttitor maximus. Nullam bibendum nunc iaculis, venenatis nibh eu, gravida urna. Sed semper laoreet ex et finibus. Morbi pharetra massa sit amet bibendum volutpat. Etiam faucibus erat diam, in pharetra urna faucibus sed. Donec aliquet est et eros laoreet iaculis. Donec faucibus enim a augue pretium auctor. 

Cras cursus, leo eu convallis venenatis, urna turpis vulputate velit, et cursus neque lacus a odio. In finibus arcu sit amet odio convallis iaculis. Duis cursus eu tellus et molestie. Donec posuere eu sapien at lacinia. Maecenas in nisl mattis, efficitur mauris in, ullamcorper erat. Suspendisse vel nibh efficitur, posuere dui a, euismod lacus. 

Quisque erat nisi, euismod id nulla et, tincidunt venenatis leo. Aenean in tincidunt magna. Proin elementum ornare viverra. Sed mattis ullamcorper fermentum. Integer pulvinar arcu quis egestas hendrerit. Curabitur ac mauris turpis. Nam aliquam scelerisque volutpat. Pellentesque varius gravida lacus vitae iaculis. 
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppressed code from the question that was not relevant to the issue discussed here. Since you are loading the geometry package, you could change `\footins` using the package (as *cfr* has suggested in a comment).

Comment: It is only necessary to load `hyperref` once. Also, shouldn't `\footins` be set using `geometry` or, preferably, the Koma-Script facilities? (I know these were not the point of the question. But there is only one `hyperref` there.)

Comment: @cfr You're right. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr So... what's the proper way to add \footins? Should it be inside "\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
headsep=10mm]{geometry}"?

Comment: @killthepixelnow `geometry` has an option `footnotesep` which sets `\footins`. If you want to keep using `geometry` (rather than a more Koma-friendly class) then, yes, this is how you should do it.

Comment: @cfr Hmmm... what's the correct way considering I'm using Koma?

Comment: @killthepixelnow See chapter 2 of the documentation for the basic use of its `typearea` facilities (loaded by the standard classes).

Answer (score 2):

Use `\noindent` and `\vspace{<dimension>}` judiciously.  (You can also use `\medskip`, or`\bigskip` instead of `\vspace{..}`) Change `1em` as you feel.

```
\begin{abstract}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel sem enim. Morbi venenatis nisl vitae elit porttitor maximus. Nullam bibendum nunc iaculis, venenatis nibh eu, gravida urna. Sed semper laoreet ex et finibus. Morbi pharetra massa sit amet bibendum volutpat. Etiam faucibus erat diam, in pharetra urna faucibus sed. Donec aliquet est et eros laoreet iaculis. Donec faucibus enim a augue pretium auctor.

\vspace{1em}\noindent
Cras cursus, leo eu convallis venenatis, urna turpis vulputate velit, et cursus neque lacus a odio. In finibus arcu sit amet odio convallis iaculis. Duis cursus eu tellus et molestie. Donec posuere eu sapien at lacinia. Maecenas in nisl mattis, efficitur mauris in, ullamcorper erat. Suspendisse vel nibh efficitur, posuere dui a, euismod lacus.

\vspace{1em}\noindent
Quisque erat nisi, euismod id nulla et, tincidunt venenatis leo. Aenean in tincidunt magna. Proin elementum ornare viverra. Sed mattis ullamcorper fermentum. Integer pulvinar arcu quis egestas hendrerit. Curabitur ac mauris turpis. Nam aliquam scelerisque volutpat. Pellentesque varius gravida lacus vitae iaculis.
\end{abstract}
```

[image]